# Is there a version of null but for list?

Tags: c#, null, generic-list, mspec

I have a unit test that I am trying to write.

I have this section as part of a working version:

```
List<MyClass> queryResult = new List<MyClass>(){};

A.CallTo(() => _dataContext.GetAll<MyClass>()).Returns(queryResult.AsQueryable());
```

However, I would rather put something like "null" instead of "queryResult.AsQueryable()", Then there would be no need to create an empty list.

But GetAll will return a list empty or full by the looks of things. Therefore, null won't work.

Is there something like "List.Empty" that I can use instead?

Thanks

Comment: How would `List.Empty` be different from an empty list?

Comment: I want to just say that it should return an empty list without having to create the object. There might not be a way, I just wondered if there was.

Comment: can't you check for count <= 0?

Comment: Empty list is an object too - so you will be forced to create an object any way.  `new List<T>` is a way

Comment: or `Enumerable.Empty<T>()`

Comment: Okay thanks Fabio I was just checking.

Comment: But when you put null you don't create an object. I just wondered if there was something like that in this instance.

Comment: @KieranMelia - what problem you trying to solve by not creating an object. Do you have performance issues ,your tests are very slow?

Comment: It just seemed inefficient, I wasn't getting any problems.

Comment: A canonical `List.Empty` instance cannot exist, since it's mutable.

Comment: Okay, thank you. But doesn't Marc's answer have the same impact as List.Empty? Are there any crucial differences?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are `Array.Empty<T>()` and `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` that might work for you. Neither of them allocates a new object per-call (they are both backed by a static `T[]` field on a generic class - `EmptyArray<T>.Value` or `EmptyEnumerable<T>.Instance`, although these are both implementation details)

Comment: That's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: Do they need specific imports to function?

Comment: @KieranMelia `Array.Empty` is only available in .net 4.6, but doesn't need any specific imports (You're almost certainly already `using System`)

Comment: Thank you. I tried Array.Empty but it says Array does not contain a definition for Empty

Comment: @KieranMelia You've done something wrong then.  Try this: `var a = System.Array.Empty<string>();`

Comment: I tried the Enumerable.Empty<MyClass>(); This is accepted as a parameter but then I get an error of System.Linq.Iqueryable cannot be converted to System.Generic.Collections.IEnumerable. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: var a = System.Array.Empty<string>(); That returned the same error. I don't know if I have conflicting imports or something.

Comment: You must do - I copy/pasted that from VS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Enumerable.Empty<MyClass>().ToList()
```

But I can not see any differences in this case.

Comment: Rather verbose, compared to `new List<MyClass>()`.